# Comparing cross-lagged coefficients in Mplus (Wald chi-sq test)

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, wald-test, mplus

I'm running a cross-lagged panel model analysis in Mplus. The cross-lagged path coefficients were constrained to be equal across time. Now, I'd like to test if the cross-lagged path from MSC to MA and the cross-lagged path from MA to MSC are statistically significantly different (i.e., (6) vs. (7) in the syntax below). I believe this is possible using Wald chi-sq test, but I wonder if someone can help me with the Mplus syntax. I'm adding the syntax that I have currently. I'd greatly appreciate your help!

VARIABLE:

Names =

```
 female

 g9achv g9ll g9iep g9like3 g9good3 g9diff3

 g6achv g6ll g6iep g6like3 g6good3 g6diff3

 g3achv g3ll g3iep g3like3 g3good3 g3diff3;
```

Missing = all(-999) ;

Usevar =

```
 female g3ll g3iep g6ll g6iep g9ll g9iep

 g9good3 g9diff3 g9like3

 g6good3 g6diff3 g6like3

 g3good3 g3diff3 g3like3

 g3achv g6achv g9achv ;
```

Categorical =

```
 g9good3 g9diff3 g9like3

 g6good3 g6diff3 g6like3

 g3good3 g3diff3 g3like3 ;
```

ANALYSIS:

Estimator = WLSMV;

Parameterization = theta;

Processors = 8;

MODEL:

! Measurement models

f_g3msc by g3good3 g3diff3 g3like3 (1-3);

f_g6msc by g6good3 g6diff3 g6like3 (1-3);

f_g9msc by g9good3 g9diff3 g9like3 (1-3);

g3good3 g3diff3 g3like3 pwith g6good3 g6diff3 g6like3 ;

g6good3 g6diff3 g6like3 pwith g9good3 g9diff3 g9like3 ;

g9good3 g9diff3 g9like3 pwith g3good3 g3diff3 g3like3 ;

! Autoregressive (AR) Terms

f_g9msc on f_g6msc (4) ; f_g6msc on f_g3msc (4) ;

g9achv on g6achv (5) ; g6achv on g3achv (5) ;

! Cross-lagged (CL) Terms

f_g9msc on g6achv (6) ; f_g6msc on g3achv (6) ;

g9achv on f_g6msc (7) ; g6achv on f_g3msc (7) ;

! Co-movements

f_g9msc with g9achv ;

f_g6msc with g6achv ;

f_g3msc with g3achv ;

! Covariates

g3achv f_g3msc on female g3iep g3ll ;

g6achv f_g6msc on female g6iep g6ll ;

g9achv f_g9msc on female g9iep g9ll ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are labeled, so you can use those labels to define a new parameter that is the difference between slopes.  Here is an example (where the slopes are indirect effects, but that part isn't relevant for you):

http://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/11/24128.html?1602803341

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the parameter labels to (a) and (b), and then added
MODEL TEST: a=b;
It worked! :)